# Dask DataFrame converts undelying parquet files index from datetime64 to object, why?

Tags: python-3.x, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I make great efforts to save my parquet files with a index using the datetime64['ns'] dtype. But when I then read multiple of the parquet files in Dask Dataframe it converts the index to dtype object (str). Why?

I cannot use parse_dates argument in my read_parquet call as it only works on columns. I read in each individual underlying parquet file with pandas and checked the dtype of the index, they are consistent.

My code is simple

```
    try:
        df = dd.read_parquet(data_filenames, columns=list(cols_to_retrieve),
                             engine='pyarrow')
    except Exception as ex:
        self.build_error(ex, end_date)

    df = df[list(cols_to_retrieve)]

    df = df.compute()
```

What is the recommended approach to fixing Dasks tendency to change dtypes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have found a bug. You should generate a little code that creates the file(s) with the datetime type, but on loading they are no longer that type, and post this at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

i.e., we need a [MCVE](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports), so that we can debug and fix, and make your example into a test against future regressions. It also often reveals something you might have been doing wrong, if there is in fact no bug.

That said, you could also try the `fastparquet` parquet engine, just in case it happens to cope with your particular data.

Comment: If anyone has an MCVE that they can share as mdurant suggested, you can share it here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8968 :)